# Possible SQLite bug?

Tags: schema, view, sqlite, metadata

I am running into an issue with SQLite that I think might be a bug. When I run the [PRAGMA table_info](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) command on a view that uses an aggregate function, the data type always comes up empty.

To duplicate the issue, create a new SQLite 3 database and add a table. Add at least one field in the table and make sure its a numeric field (such as integer or float or something). Then create a new view with a `SELECT` statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT *, Sum(MyField) AS MySumField FROM MyTable
```

Now run `sqlite3 <database_name>` and type the following:

```
PRAGMA table_info(MyView);
```

You will notice there is no data type for some reason. Here is my output when I issued the command:

```
0|Field1|INTEGER|0||0
1|Field2|INTEGER|0||0
2|Field3|FLOAT|0||0
3|SumField2||0||0
```

Does anybody know if this is an actual bug and if there is a workaround for this behavior?

Comment: Can you post your exact version?

Comment: @TomV - I'm using the latest. Version 3.8.10.2.

Comment: You are assuming that columns have data types. [This is not the case](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662099/sqlite3-table-info-for-a-view-what-table-does-the-column-come-from)